# How to write a YUV422/YUV420 video data (Y,U,V buffers) to buffer of a video playback card?

Tags: c++, c, video, yuv, pixelformat

I want to display videos to a video playback card , if the pixel format is RGBA/BGRA I can write video data to card buffer because it is so easy, but if pixel format is YUV422/YUV420 it is not easy (at least to me) and I don't know how can write 3 Y,U,V data buffers to ONE buffer of playback card.
I googled , but could not find my answer.

Please look at the following my code snippet and comments :

```
       if(f== SDL_PIXELFORMAT_BGRA32)
        {
           ret = SDL_UpdateTexture(*tex, NULL, frame->data[0], frame->linesize[0]); //the SDL display video perfectly
          
           if (myCardBuffer)
            {
              int straid = frame->linesize[0] * frame->height;
                 memcpy(myCardBuffer, frame->data[0], straid); //card frame is bmdFormat8BitBGRA and works perfectly
            }
        }
        else  if (f == SDL_PIXELFORMAT_IYUV) //   Planar mode: Y + U + V  (3 planes) 
         {
                ret = SDL_UpdateYUVTexture(*tex, NULL,
                    frame->data[0], frame->linesize[0],frame->data[1], frame->linesize[1],  frame->data[2], frame->linesize[2]);//the SDL display video perfectly
         
         if (myCardBuffer)
            {
                  //card frame is bmdFormat8BitYUV but I dont know how to write 3 Y,U,V data buffers to it 
            }
         }
```

and this is information about the pixel format of the card :

[image]

Question : How to write a YUV422/YUV420 video data (Y,U,V buffers) to the buffer of the card?

Comment: why don’t you convert to RGB and then write?

Comment: @ manishg , I can convert it to RGB , but I want to know/learn about YUV. Also I think if I can use YUV directly it will get better performance than RGB;

Comment: So if you have three different plane buffers, you order them as per the format and feed in a single buffer. for 4:2:2: byte 0 = first byte of U plane i.e U0, byte 1 = first byte of Y plane i.e. Y0, byte 2 = first byte of V plane i.e. V0, byte 3 = second byte of Y plane i.e. Y1 and so on... Did you get it? @MitraM. Please note U and V are subsampled so leave out the odd bytes like this U0 Y0 V0 Y1 U2 Y2 V2 Y3...